# How to get increase percentage along row-wise in time series data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have time series dataframe where I want to calculate increase/decrease percentage along row-wise for each column in time series data. To do so, I can try nested loop to iterate column and rows then do the calculation but it is not working correctly. Can anyone point me out any tweak to make this happen? Is there any way to get this done in pandas?

**my attempt**

here is my [time series data in this gist](https://gist.github.com/jaret20/93b9bd616a8f6ac833e821c1e05079a4):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("mydf.csv")

for col in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    for row1 in range(0, len(df)):
        for row2 in range(1, len(df)):
            numerator = df[row2][col] - df[row][col]
            denominator = df[row][col]
            perc_change = numerator/denomintor
            print(perc_change)
```

above attempt is not working. I also tried like this:

```
for col in range(0, len(df.columns)):
     df.div(df[col], axis=0).applymap(lambda x: f'{x * 100:.2f}%')
```

my second attempt is not working correctly also. Can anyone point me out how to get this right? Any thoughts?

**desired output**:

this is just dummy example output that only shows structure of my desired output. My desired output would be increase/decrease percentage of current rows w.r.t previous one in each column. here is [example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b30Qq.png)

how can we make this happen correctly? Any idea to make this right in pandas? Thanks!

Comment: `df.set_index('dates', inplace=True); df = df.diff() / df.shift()`

Comment: @CodeDifferent how could we make the output of percentage as `{100:.2f}%`? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Adam, in the resulting data frame, see Code DIfferent's solution, apply the following code. df = df.apply(lambda row: np.round(row.values, 3)*100), where np is numpy (import numpy as np)

Comment: @griggy thanks, it worked. Couple you make an answer for this since it is my first post, I'd like to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Adam, I think credit should go to CodeDifferent. Cheers